# Page Object Model -- Kotlin -- Testing

Tags: android, kotlin, testing, android-espresso, android-testing

I need help with Page Object Model pattern in Android. I keep getting this error for the verify() method on page.verify(); I have tried adding MockK dependencies. I am still new at Android testing. Any advice is very much appreciated!

Resources: https://hanru-yeh.medium.com/pageobject-pattern-by-kotlin-into-android-ui-tests-1df8e0b72b69

```
open class Page {
companion object {
    inline fun <reified T : Page> on(): T {
        return Page().on()
    }
}
inline fun <reified T : Page> on(): T {
    val page = T::class.constructors.first().call()
    page.verify()
    return page
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can add an open function like this.

```
open fun verify() {

}
```

And then, each class extending from `Page` should implement that function.